# R Studio crashes when running bigvis condense() and bin()

Tags: r, macos

I am trying to use bigvis package bin() and condense() on a large data set. I am using the example data set at http://data.had.co.nz/13-flights/dist.rds

This is what I am doing:

```
> require(bigvis)
> dist<-readRDS("data/dist.rds)
> summary(dist)
     Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
     6.0   323.0   581.0   732.1   964.0  4963.
> dist_s <-condense(bin(dist,10))
```

After a few seconds R Studio aborts with the error message "R session aborted, R encountered a fatal error, the session was terminated" with a bomb and lit fuse image.

I am running R Studio Version 0.98.490 on OS X 10.9.1 and R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue after I updated the library `Rcpp` to version 0.11.0

In order to fix it, I had to roll-back to the previous version of `Rcpp`, which is 0.10.6.0

I downloaded the older version of Rcpp from http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/Rcpp/

Then in the bash terminal (not in R) I ran:

`R CMD INSTALL ~/Downloads/Rcpp_0.10.6.tar.gz`

I then restarted my R environment and `bigvis` was working fine again.